# Using DOTALL breaks re.sub after replacing multiple times

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to call re.sub on decently large chunks of text. The weird thing is that it looks like after 16 replacements suddenly stops replacing anything. But if I get rid of the DOTALL flag, then it suddenly works again.

My input file:

```
<a>
<a>
<a>
<a>
.... (repeats about 100 times)
```

The code/regex I'm using:

```
import re
file = open("temp.txt", 'r')
text = ''
for line in file:
    text += line
print re.sub(".*", "", text, re.DOTALL)
```

What it printed:

```
(15 blank lines)



...
<a>
<a>
<a>
...
```

Clearly what is supposed to be returned is an empty string. The strange thing is that if DOTALL is excluded, then I get all empty lines (with the newlines left as expected). If I try this with other regex strings, then it runs those correctly, but only ever 15 times max.

Any idea why this would happen? Or am I just going insane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4th parameter for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is `count`, not a `flags`, You should specify it with keyword argument `flags=`.

```
print re.sub(".*", "", text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Without keyword argument, it will mean `count=16` (re.DOTALL = 16); resulting replacement take place only 16 times at most.

Comment: Wow, this makes so much more sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: What you mean by this `re.DOTALL = 16` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Try `print re.DOTALL` in python interactive shell. You will get what I mean. (flags are integer values that can be bitwise ORed)

Comment: This also explains why the number of replacements changed based on what flags I ORed with the DOTALL.